# If Else Statement with Four Criteria returning NA

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
Pars <-structure(list(Pars.PeopleSoftID = c(11, 18, 18, 22, 39, 181), 
    Pars..Central.1. = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pars..Central.2. = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pars.External = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5), Pars.Minimum = c(15, 
    2, 1.71, 1, 1, 4.39), Pars.Maximum = c(15, 2.76, 2, 1, 1, 
    5.48)), .Names = c("Pars.PeopleSoftID", "Pars..Central.1.", 
"Pars..Central.2.", "Pars.External", "Pars.Minimum", "Pars.Maximum"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to add a column that calculates a number based on what is in the columns Central 1, Central 2, and External and multiplies that number by the value in Pars$Minimum.

The logic is:

If Central 1 = 0, Central 2 = 0, External = 0 THEN <-- 0 * Pars$Minimum

If Central 1 = 1, Central 2 = 0, External = 0 THEN <-- 1 * Pars$Minimum

If Central 1 = 1, Central 2 = 1, External = 0 THEN <-- 0.7 * Pars$Minimum

If Central 1 = 1, Central 2 = 1, External > 0 THEN <-- 0.7 * Pars$Minimum

If Central 1 = 1, Central 2 = 0, External > 0 THEN <-- 0.8 * Pars$Minimum

I just tried this, but it seems to be just returning values of NA for everything:

```
 Pars$Cen1 <- with(Pars, if(`Central 1` == 0 , 0, ifelse(`Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 0 & External == 0, 1, ifelse(`Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 1 & External == 0, .7, ifelse(`Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 1 & External > 0, .7, ifelse(`Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 0 & External > 0, .8)
```

Comment: should the first `if` be `ifelse`? `dplyr::case_when` is probably nicer than nested `ifelse` statements

Comment: Note that the column names in the `Pars` data.frame provided in the question are: `c("Pars.PeopleSoftID", "Pars..Central.1.", "Pars..Central.2.", "Pars.External", "Pars.Minimum", "Pars.Maximum")` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is to make a map of values and lookup the conditions pasted together there:

```
  valuemap = c("000" = 0, "001"= 0, "100"= 1, "110"= 0.7, "111" = 0.7, "101" = 0.8)

  Pars$Cen1 <- Pars$Pars.Minimum * 
    valuemap[paste0(Pars$Pars..Central.1.,Pars$Pars..Central.2., 
                    1 * (Pars$Pars.External > 0))]
```

Comment: How do you know what do when instead of `==` there's switching between `!=` `<` `<=` etc?

Comment: Well, if it's too complex it breaks down. as long as each condition is essentially binary, i just need a way to map the condition to 0 and 1. It's possible to do it with more complex conditions, but at some point I would certainly switch back to ifelse or case_when.

Comment: @ChristophWolk That's so great! Much easier to do. If I wanted to use an operator like >=1, how would I need to map the values? Would it be "0>=01" or does there need to be some sort of separator?

Comment: Well, you have to get it into a string somehow. If it's simply x  >= 0, I would use "0" to mean less than 1, and 1 to mean more than or exactly 1. So I would have strings with 0 or 1 at that position in that string,  and in the `paste0` someling like `1*(theValueToCheck >=1)`.

Answer (score 3):

I renamed some of your columns as well, wasnt sure why each column name needed to be called "Pars." if the table was already called Pars, but this works here to do what you want, should give you a format to use.

```
Pars <-structure(list(Pars.PeopleSoftID = c(11, 18, 18, 22, 39, 181), 
    Pars..Central.1. = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pars..Central.2. = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pars.External = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5), Pars.Minimum = c(15, 
    2, 1.71, 1, 1, 4.39), Pars.Maximum = c(15, 2.76, 2, 1, 1, 
    5.48)), .Names = c("PeopleSoftID", "Central.1", 
"Central.2", "External", "Minimum", "Maximum"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Pars$Cen1 <- with(Pars,ifelse(Central.1 == 0 & Central.2 == 0 & External == 0,0*Minimum,
                       ifelse(Central.1 == 1 & Central.2 == 0 & External == 0,1*Minimum, 
                       ifelse(Central.1 == 1 & Central.2 == 1 & External >= 0,0.7*Minimum,
                       ifelse(Central.1 == 1 & Central.2 == 0 & External > 0,.8*Minimum,0)))))
```

Comment: why are you returning `0` for last `ifelse`?

Comment: @PoGibas Just plugged it with something, she didnt specify if she wanted a NULL or something else. Just replace the 0 with whatever you want the value to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(Pars, Cen1 = case_when(
    `Central 1` == 0 & `Central 2` == 0 & External == 0 ~ 0 * Minimum,
    `Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 0 & External == 0 ~ 1 * Minimum,
    `Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 1 & External == 0 ~ 0.7 * Minimum,
    `Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 1 & External > 0 ~ 0.7 * Minimum,
    `Central 1` == 1 & `Central 2` == 0 & External > 0 ~ 0.8 * Minimum))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your final ifelse statement has only two arguments, so if you ever get to trying to assign the value of that 'no' statement, you'll get an error.

This seemed to work for me:

```
Pars$Cen1 <- ifelse(Pars$Pars..Central.1. == 0, 0, 
                ifelse(Pars$Pars..Central.1. == 1 & Pars$Pars..Central.2. == 0 & Pars$Pars.External == 0, 1, 
                       ifelse(Pars$Pars..Central.1. == 1 & Pars$Pars..Central.2. == 1 & Pars$Pars.External == 0, .7, 
                              ifelse(Pars$Pars..Central.1. == 1 & Pars$Pars..Central.2. == 1 & Pars$Pars.External > 0, .7, 
                                     ifelse(Pars$Pars..Central.1. == 1 & Pars$Pars..Central.2. == 0 & Pars$Pars.External > 0, .8, "Missing")))))
```